# Remove item from Nested list Java Stream

Tags: java, java-8

I'll appreciate some help with this please. Assuming I have

```
            "bookingId": 4,
            "flights": [
                {   ...
                    "flightNumber": "AUS382",
                },
                {    ...
                    "flightNumber": "ZOD498",
                }
            ]
        },
```

and i  want to remove flights with `flightNumber` of `ZOD498` alone, how do i go about that?

I've tried
`passengerBooking.removeIf(e -> e.getFlights().stream().anyMatch(flightToRemove))`

where `a` is a predicate -  `Predicate<Flight> flightToRemove = e -> "ZOD498".equals(e.getFlightNumber())`

That kinda works, but removes the whole `flight` object, so the output now becomes

```
"bookingId": 4,
            "flights": [
            ]
        },
```

Please what modification do i need to make to remove a specific flight and have a result similar to

```
"bookingId": 4,
            "flights": [
                {   ...
                    "flightNumber": "AUS382",
                }
                
            ]
        },
```

Thank You

Comment: please share a Java reproducible example, so we can just copy it and run it

Comment: hard to say without seeing rest of the code but you're probably looking for something like: `passengerBooking.forEach(booking -> booking.getFlights()
                .removeIf(flight -> "nrToRemove".equals(flight.getFlightNumber())));`

Comment: @azro. Dan shared one before i could do that. Thank you too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a class `PassengerBooking` with a `List` of objects `Flight`, and that the `passengerBooking` variable represents a `List` of objects `PassengerBooking`.

You could traverse the items of your `List`. Then, for each `PassengerBooking` object retrieve the `List` of Flight with the corresponding getter and then invoke the `removeIf` method on the `Collection` returned.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<PassengerBooking> passengerBooking = new ArrayList<>(List.of(
                new PassengerBooking(4, new ArrayList<>(List.of(
                        new Flight("AUS382"),
                        new Flight("ZOD498")
                )))
        ));

        System.out.println(passengerBooking);

        for (PassengerBooking passenger: passengerBooking){
            passenger.getFlights().removeIf(f -> f.getFlightNumber().equals("ZOD498"));
        }

        System.out.println(passengerBooking);
    }
}
```

Besides, if this is a common operation for your `PassengerBooking` class, you could think of implementing a custom method to remove a `Flight` by its id.

This is a simple assumption of your classes' implementation to test the code above.

```
class PassengerBooking {
    private int bookingId;
    private List<Flight> flights;

    public PassengerBooking(int bookingId, List<Flight> flights) {
        this.bookingId = bookingId;
        this.flights = flights;
    }

    public int getBookingId() {
        return bookingId;
    }

    public List<Flight> getFlights() {
        return flights;
    }

    //Custom utility method
    public void removeFlight(String flightID){
        flights.removeIf(f -> f.getFlightNumber().equals("ZOD498"));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%d => %s", bookingId, flights);
    }
}

class Flight {
    private String flightNumber;

    public Flight(String flightNumber) {
        this.flightNumber = flightNumber;
    }

    public String getFlightNumber() {
        return flightNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return flightNumber;
    }
}
```